# symfony: question about routes and url_for()

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have this route:

```
category_set_representative_image:
  url:     /categoria-settare-immaggine-rappresentativa
  param:   { module: category_new, action: setRepresentativeImage }
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: Category, type: object }
```

and a link associated to this:

```
url_for('category_set_representative_image', array('sf_subject' => $category))
```

When I click the link I get:

> sfError404Exception: Action
>   "categoriasettareimmagginerappresentativa/index" does not
>   exist.

Any idea?

**EDIT** after the answer of Flask:

This is my code, no problems if I call the same `url_for()` out of javascript tags.

```
<script>
    $.post('<?php echo url_for('category_set_representative_image', array('sf_subject' => $category)) ?>',
           function(){

             alert("fadsf");
           }
    );
</script>
```

sf 1.4

Javi

Comment: have you tried the url in the routing yml without the '-' characters ?

Comment: Open the same page in the dev environment and check the toolbar to see which route its matching - my guess would be the default one - its not finding your route

Comment: @ManseUK, where "exactly" in the web debug toolbar can I see the route that is being matching??

Comment: its on the Logs section of the web debug toolbar - here is an example from a local app im running : 1  sfPatternRouting Match route "default" (/:module/:action/*) for /tariff/edit/id/1 with parameters array ( 'module' => 'tariff', 'action' => 'edit', 'id' => '1',)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for routes you will have to add "@" before the route: `url_for('@category_set_representative_image', array('sf_subject' => $category))`

do you have you the default route at the end of the routing.yml?

Comment: I don't think the "@" is obligatory, it will just serve to call url_for1() or url_for2(), in my case I want to call url_for2, so I don't have to add it. More: Yes, I had a default route at the end, and now I have removed it, and I'm getting this error: sfError404Exception: Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL '/categoria-settare-immaggine-rappresentativa'. I paste the code in my question.

Comment: Wrong! If you put "@" at the beginning, the second arg of url_for denotes if the URL is absolute or not. A parameter-array as second url_for-arg is allowed if, AND ONLY IF, the first arg contains the route name (and therefore no slashes) without a leading "@"!

Comment: @fishbone wrong. `@` refers to the **routename** not the the url. as mentioned [here](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/05?orm=Propel)

Comment: No, you have to pass the route name without leading "@". There is also an example in the link you mentioned. As soon as you use "@" or "/" you must append params in the first url_for-arg (`@myroute?myparam=val` or `mod/act?myparam=val`). Just look at the url_for-code. I even used a debugger to proof what I said. See here: [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/helper/UrlHelper.php#L127) and [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/helper/UrlHelper.php#L100)

Answer (score 1):

Currently it isn't executing the rule above.

You probably have a more generic routing rule before this rule. (the default `/:module/:action` rule?)