# symfony: about passing parameters with url_for()

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have this line in a template:

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('category_set_representative_image', array('aux' => 4, 'sf_subject' => $category)) ?>">jander</a>
```

So as you can guess when I click that link, it executes an action. Inside that action I have this:

```
var_dump($request->getParameter('aux'));var_dump($request->getParameter('sf_subject'));die("fasf");
```

It's printing 4 and NULL. Why NULL? I expected the $category object was showed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the sf_subject parameter that way. You can only use the sf_subject with the sfDoctrineRoute or sfPropelRoute. In your code, you can then get the selected object with `$this->getRoute()->getObject()`.

Comment: Thanks Grad,it works :). I would like to accept this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995530/symfony-question-about-routes-and-url-for but I can't find a solution, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What is the html representation of your first line?

Seems like in your template `$category` is not defined, so the `< a >`  should looks like

```
foo.php?aux=4&sf_subject=null or
foo.php?aux=4
```

Define the category in your template :-)